# Mostrar un elemento de un JSON con un ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

¿Cómo puedo mostrar la iP que pertenece a un "ip_id" dentro de elementos?.

data.json

```
{
"json": [{
    "list_ip": [{
        "1": "190.15.20.18",
        "2": "10.10.10.100",
        "3": "10.20.30.40"
    }],
    "cosas": [{
        "elementos": [{
                "ip_id": 1
            },
            {
                "ip_id": 3
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

}

javascript

```
    $.each( data.json, function(index_json, valores ) {

      $.each(valores.cosas.elementos, function(index_elementos, valores_elementos){
        /*Aqui se debería mostrar la IP que pertenece a ese ip_id*/
        /*por ejemplo = "190.15.20.18"*/
        console.log(valores_elementos.ip_id:1);
      });
    });
```

Resultado:

> ```
> 190.15.20.18
> ```

Comment: Creo que la solución mas practica es reformular la extructa JSON que estas usando, mas que hacer una funcion rebuscada para dicha tarea.

Comment: Pregunta, En el json List ip y cosas siempre vienen en la posicion 0, y elementos y list_ip tambien vienen en la posicion 0, o tienes la intencion de poner otras en medio del json, si es asi, la estructura del json está mal

Comment: todo es variable, este json solo es un ejemplo pero en la realidad es mas complejo, pero siempre sera al mismo nivel

Comment: No se puede cambiar la estructura del JSON ya que la crea un robot y se debería cambiar el robot

Comment: Con esta estructura de json, no tienes muchas opciones amigo, para que lo que pienso funcione, tienes que garantizar que el robot te devolverá (cosas e ip_list) en la posición 0 , si no es así, antes tendrías que buscar esas variables en la posición que hayan quedado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo la complicación. Si como dices, siempre los datos están al mismo nivel, basta con:

1. Obtener la lista de ips.
2. Obtener el array de elementos.
3. Realizar un foreach para agregar a un nuevo objeto, los ips encontrados de acuerdo al `id_ip` de cada objeto dentro de `elementos`.

```js
const data = {
  "json": [
    {
      "list_ip": [
        {
          "1": "190.15.20.18",
          "2": "10.10.10.100",
          "3": "10.20.30.40"
        }
      ],
      "cosas": [
        {
          "elementos": [
             {
               "ip_id": 1
             },
             {
               "ip_id": 3
             }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


function mapIPs() {
  const ips = data.json[0].list_ip[0];
  const els = data.json[0].cosas[0].elementos;
  const associations = {};
  
  els.forEach(el => {
    for(let [key, val] of Object.entries(el)) {
      if (ips[val]) {
        associations[val] = ips[val];
      }
    }
  });
  
  return associations;
}

console.info(mapIPs());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me sirvió tu checklist, el código no pero pude hacerlo gracias a eso, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este ejemplo funcionando, ya que la estructura de ese JSON no es muy útil para relacionar. En caso de que las ip_list y los elementos no estuviesen en la posición 0 debes hacer otro algoritmo para buscar esas variables y almacenarlas en las variables correspondientes.

```
    var jsonEstilo1=[
    {
        "list_ip": [
            {
                "1": "190.15.20.18",
                "2": "10.10.10.100",
                "3": "10.20.30.40"
            }
        ],
        "cosas": [
            {
                "elementos": [
                    {
                        "ip_id": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "ip_id": 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

    function searchlistIpEstilo1(id){
        //----- La lista de ip asumiento que siempre estará en la posicion 0
        var iplist=jsonEstilo1[0].list_ip[0];
        if(id in iplist){
            return iplist[id];
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    //----- La lista de elmentos asumiento que siempre estará en la posicion 0
      var elementos=jsonEstilo1[0].cosas[0].elementos;
    for(var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
        var result=searchlistIpEstilo1(elementos[i].ip_id);
        if(result!=null){
            console.log(result);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como extraer las **ip** según el valor de **ip_id** :

```js
obj = {
 "json": [{
  "list_ip": [{
   "1": "190.15.20.18",
   "2": "10.10.10.100",
   "3": "10.20.30.40"
  }],
  "cosas": [{
   "elementos": [{
    "ip_id": 1
   },{
    "ip_id": 3
   }]
  }]
 }]
}
display(obj,"","ip_id");

function display(xobj,sp,search) {
 for (n in xobj) {
  if (typeof xobj[n] == 'object') {
   display(xobj[n],n+".");
  }else{
   if (n=="ip_id")
    html.innerHTML+="<p>"+sp+n+"="+xobj[n]+" ("+obj.json[0].list_ip[0][xobj[n]]+")";
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="html"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Así lo solucioné:

```
        var ips;    
        var ip_ids;
        $.each( data.json, function(index_json, valores ) {
          ips = valores.list_ip
          $.each(valores.cosas.elementos, function(index_elementos, valores_elementos){
            ip_ids = valores_elementos.ip_id;
            $.each(ips, function(index_ip, valor_ips){
                    ip_el = valor_ips[ip_ids];
            });
          console.log(ip_el);
          });
        });
```